# Can unused mortar that freezes be used?

Tags: mortar

I left a bag of opened Porcelain mortar in the garage for a week and during that time the temperature got below freezing. Can I use this mortar or does it have to be thrown out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it is dry, you are good to use it. If it has been exposed to excess humidity in any temperature it will harden in the bag.